# how to select unique values from sqlite table in iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, sqlite, unique

I have data in my sqlite table like the following

here is the my table description and fields

```
    coffeeID;
category;
sub_Category;
content_Type;
content_Title;
content_Description;
content_Id;
publisher;
content_Source;
update_date_time;
```

and here is the code where i am now getting all values but i want unique values.

```
       const char *sql = "select * from category";


    sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
            Coffee *coffeeObj = [[Coffee alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];
            coffeeObj.category=sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt,1);
            coffeeObj.sub_Category = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 2)];
            coffeeObj.content_Type = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 3)];
            coffeeObj.content_Title = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,4)];

            coffeeObj.publisher = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 5)];
            coffeeObj.content_Description = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 6)];
            coffeeObj.content_Id = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 7)];
            coffeeObj.content_Source = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 8)];

            int count=[appDelegate.coffeeArray count];

            NSLog(@"count is beofore getting values %d",count);



            [appDelegate.coffeeArray addObject:coffeeObj];



            int countone=[appDelegate.coffeeArray count];

            NSLog(@"count is after getting values %d",countone);

            [coffeeObj release];
        }
    }
}
```

I want that if it has two same sub categories then it may show only one like mean only unique records not the categories with same name repeated.

Comment: Since you're using the subcategory field, if the category has 2 subcategories, which would you like returned since you can then only return one row per category?

Comment: Better still, could you add a concrete example of what you're getting now and a desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Group by in SQL Query

```
"Select * From category GROUP BY category"
```

You can group by any column

Comment: means ? What do you want, u can use DISTINCT also

Comment: i want that in my table there catgories Diabestes and oncology and they many records in table i want those recors which are uniuqe like in diabetes category there is Glucon two time then it may show one time

Comment: is this query right   const char *sql = "select * from category GROUP BY sub_Category where category='Diabetes'";

Comment: NO, can u be clear, if u want one records with same sub_category or you want group of records with same sub_category ??

Comment: i want record where category is Diabetes and group by subCategory